# Radon meausre in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I try to find a Radon Measure $\nu$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that there exists a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ with $\lambda^2(S) = 0$ and $\nu(S) >0$. $\lambda^2$ is the Lebesgue measure.
Furthermore I want $\nu$ to satisfy $\nu(A) = 0$ for all sets $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ with cardinality $1$.

I know that the Radon measures in $\mathbb{R}$ are the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measures. Maybe there is some analogue to this in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Obviously, I can not choose a measure with density.

Comment: Radon measures don't have that analogue in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (and can behave very badly because of the extra freedom, e.g. it can be $1$-rectifiable yet singular wrt 1D Hausdorff measure) but you can construct an example which is purely based on familiar Radon measures on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks. You mean a product measure?

Comment: Yes, that's a good starting point.

Comment: Try $\nu(E)=\lambda^1\{x\in\mathbb R: (x,0)\in E\}$.

Comment: Looks fine at first sight!